# Perl Regex Query - filter the contents inside the file which are older than 18 months

Tags: bash, shell, date, perl

I have a problem where I want to filter the contents inside the file which are older than 18 months.

File looks like this:

```sh
 > cat trans_file.txt

trans-02-2018
trans-03-2019
trans-04-2021
trans-01-2022
```

Output needed:

```
trans-02-2018
trans-03-2019
```

I am using below method:

```sh
export DT=`date +%m-%Y`
export DTLastYear=`date +%m-%Y -d '18 months ago'`
perl -ne 'print if grep {$_<$ENV{$DTLastYear}}  /(\d{2}-\d{4})/g' trans_file.txt
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Is `awk` also possible?

Comment: `<` should be `lt`, and you would need to reorder the year and month

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it in pure `perl`, using core time-processing modules instead of `date(1)` to get the 18 months ago date (And parse the date from the lines instead of using regular expressions):

As a one-liner:

```sh
$ perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -lne '
  BEGIN { $when = localtime() - (ONE_MONTH * 18) }
  my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "trans-%m-%Y");
  print if defined $t && $t < $when;' trans_file.txt
trans-02-2018
trans-03-2019
```

Or as a separate script that takes the input file name(s) as command line arguments, or reads from standard input if there are none:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use v5.22.0; # For <<>>; use the less-secure <> on older perls
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $when = localtime() - (ONE_MONTH * 18);

while (my $line = <<>>) {
    chomp $line;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($line, "trans-%m-%Y");
    say $line if defined $t && $t < $when;
}
```

---

Or using the non-core but often useful [`DateTime` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) mentioned by zdim:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use v5.22.0; # For <<>>; use the less-secure <> on older perls
use DateTime; # Install through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client

my $when = DateTime->now->truncate(to => 'month')->subtract(months => 18);

while (my $line = <<>>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /(\d\d)-(\d{4})$/) {
        my $t = DateTime->new(month => $1, year => $2);
        say $line if $t < $when;
    }
}
```

---

#### Where you went wrong

All of the above convert times to objects that can be compared, instead of using strings like your attempt (Though in `perl` you need `lt` instead of `<` to compare strings). It can also be done that way, but you have to use a date format that can be meaningfully compared as strings. You're trying to use a 'MM-YYYY' format , but that doesn't sort properly - `01-2020` comes before `12-2019`, for example, because 0 is before 1. If you switch it around to a 'YYYY-MM' format, you can make it work using string comparison.

`bash` example:

```sh
dt_last_year=$(date +%Y-%m -d '18 months ago')
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ([0-9][0-9])-([0-9]{4})$ ]]; then
        # date in YYYY-MM format
        t="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if [[ $t < $dt_last_year ]]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$line"
        fi
    fi
done < trans_file.txt
```

Comment: @zdim I went with just core modules to avoid additional dependencies.

Comment: Getting this error >   BEGIN { $when = localtime() - (ONE_MONTH * 18) }
>   my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "trans-%m-%Y");
>   print if defined $t && $t < $when;' trans_file.txt
Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @damanaulakh88 It's a standard module (I think it was added in 5.10?). So if you're getting that error, something's messed up with your perl installation. Or you're using an extremely old and obsolete version of perl.

Comment: Note that your Time::Piece and DateTime snippets use UTC, not local time.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`:

```
x=$(date +%Y-%m -d '18 months ago')

while IFS='-' read -r prefix month year; do
  [[ "$year-$month" < "$x" ]] && echo "$prefix-$month-$year";
done < file
```

Output:

```
trans-02-2018
trans-03-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

`<` is for numerical comparisons. You need to use `lt` for string comparisons.
You need to reorder the year and month to use a string comparison.
You want string `DTLastYear`, not variable `$DTLastYear`.

Fixed:

```sh
export DTLastYear=`date +%Y-%m -d '18 months ago'`
perl -ne'/(\d{2})-(\d{4})/ or next; print if "$2-$1" lt $ENV{DTLastYear}' trans_file.txt
```

Simplified:

```sh
export DTLastYear=`date +%Y-%m -d '18 months ago'`
perl -F- -lane'print if "$F[2]-$F[1]" lt $ENV{DTLastYear}' trans_file.txt
```